Authentication in Spring Security using data from database
I am trying to create a Spring Boot Application. I have created a table with username and password. I tried to configure Spring Security use data from that table to authenticate the users. But I am getting the following error:
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-04-20T17:49:38.211+05:00 ERROR 15840 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:227) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4] 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]   
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:409) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4] 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]   
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:362) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:334) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at com.nurlikum.ReportSystem.config.SecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.passwordEncoder(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.nurlikum.ReportSystem.config.SecurityConfig.configureGlobal(SecurityConfig.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]     
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4] 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]   
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:959) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at com.nurlikum.ReportSystem.ReportSystemApplication.main(ReportSystemApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]

Here is my entity class:
package com.nurlikum.ReportSystem;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Employees {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    int id;

    String name;

    String password;

    public Employees(){}

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employees{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name=" + name +
                ", password=" + password +
                '}';
    }
}


I have created a CustomUserDetails class:
package com.nurlikum.ReportSystem;



import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeesRepository employeesRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Employees employees = employeesRepository.findByName(username);

        if(employees == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username+" not found");
        }
        return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withUsername(employees.getName())
            .password(employees.getPassword())
            .roles("USER")
            .build();
        
    }
}


And here is my configuration class:
package com.nurlikum.ReportSystem.config;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import com.nurlikum.ReportSystem.CustomUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        
        return http
                    .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("/h2/**"))
                    .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                            .requestMatchers("/h2/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/addEmployee").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/history").authenticated()
                            .anyRequest().permitAll())
                    .headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(frameOptions -> frameOptions.sameOrigin()))
                    .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                    .build();
    }

}


The IDE is not showing any errors, but when I run the application I am getting the error.
Here are my dependencies:
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
     <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
     <version>1.7</version>
   </dependency>
 
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
     <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
     <version>7.0.0</version>
   </dependency>
 
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>

I tried to Google the error message, but it did not find anything. I uploaded all the code snippets and the error on ChatGpt, it could not help and it is giving codes from old Spring Boot versions.
I just want the Spring Boot to authenticate users using the data in the Employees database.

you can delete configureGlobal function entirely, as spring will by itself figure out where to place the password encode and user details service, and you would of know this if you read the spring security docs. And you can delete the dependency spring-security-core

It solved the issue. I will read the docs too, thank you very much

In the CustomUserDetailsService instead of using Field injection you can resolve this issue(Circular Dependency Injection) by injecting bean of EmployeesRepository through Contructor Injection
`
private EmployeesRepository employeesRepository;

@Autowired
public CustomUserDetailsService(EmployeesRepository employeesRepository) {
    this.employeesRepository = employeesRepository;
}`


thanks for the response, but I got exactly the same error
